# Ubuntu KVM guest-only bridged network?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, linux-kvm

Configuring a bridge is not a problem [KVM Networking](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Networking)

What I can't figure out is how to disconnect host from the bridge?

Comment: Now I think this question belongs to serverfault. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove ip from the bridge like that:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual

auto br1
iface br1 inet manual
    bridge_ports eth1
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 0
```